# What is the general term for Activity in Android and ViewController in ios?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I would like to say a mobile application is consists of "something" and resources.

What I try to mean by "something" is part of the execution. (like code..)

More specifically, I would like to say "something" is Activities or ViewController.

Is there a general word for Activity in Android and ViewController in ios?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call Activity in Android or ViewController in iOS a **Controller** :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder if **Controller** is a common word to everyone.

Comment: Yes, I think "Controller" is a common word :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I'm not mistaken, the word you are looking for is a Context. To be more specific, a *God Object*. In simplest terms, a God Object is an OOP principle that describes an object that knows too much. Similarly, I believe for iOS this is known as a *God Model*. This is a common anti-pattern, and there are design patterns you can follow to avoid delegating too much responsibility to a single class. But this is not the place to start that thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have never heard about God Object and God Model. I should study those more. Thank you!